# Filter by most recent association for all objects ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, psql

Say I've got an object `Assignment` that `has_many :exercises`

What is the best way to scope assignments based on ONLY the most recent `exercise` for each object? Or, how can I select only the `Exercise` that is the most recent for each assignment?

Something like this is what I'm imagining for the latter:

```
Exercise.distinct(:assignment_id)
```

But that doesn't work. (Returns all Exercises) I've also tried

```
Exercise.group(:assignment_id)
```

But that complains that the `exercises.id` column must also appear in the group clause. However, adding that groups by both `assignment_id` and `id` (obviously), which, again, returns all Exercises.

My other option, which I'd also like to know how to do (Never seems to work out as well as I want) is to be able to filter `assignments` based on the most recent exercise.

```
Assignment.where("most_recent_exercise.created_at <= ?", DateTime.current.beginning_of_day)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

As an example, given the below objects (Assume created in the order the ids are given)

```
Assignment 1
  Exercise 1
  Exercise 2
  Exercise 3

Assignment 2
  Exercise 4

Assignment 3
  Exercise 5
  Exercise 6
```

I want to be able to call

`Exercise.most_recent` and get exercises `3, 4, 6` since they are the most recently created Exercise for their respective Assignments.

Answer (score 1):

> how can I select only the Exercise that is the most recent for each assignment?

```
@assignment.exercises.order(:created_at).last
```

This is not pretty, but may work:

```
Exercise.where(
  id: Exercise.all.order(:assignment_id, :created_at).
      map{|e| e.attributes.with_indifferent_access}.
      group_by{|e| e[:assignment_id]}.
      map{|k,v| v.first}.
      map{|e| e[:id]}
)
```

Comment: That will only get the assignment for the very most recent Exercise. I want the most recent exercise for each Assignment.

Comment: Again, that's only returning a single Exercise. I'd like to return EVERY Exercise that is the last occurrence for any given assignment.

Comment: Updated post with example.

Comment: The most recent edit may work, but is extremely slow. :( I have a non-sql version that does what I want, but don't like the loss of speed and efficiency. Thanks for your help! For now I'm going to go with a pluck and Ruby grouping method to get the ids and just use those instead.